# Only Internet Explorer shows 500 error at oauth connection to Tumblr Api

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth, tumblr

I've searched the internet around for the following issue but found topics whose solution didn't help me or topics with no solutions. So here it goes:

For my php application I need to connect to Tumblr by way of oAuth and Tumblrs API. In Google Chrome, Firefox and Opera the process of getting tokens and building the authorize link and sending the user there everything runs perfectly. However, in Internet Explorer a 500 error (internet server error) is returned.

I traced the problem down to this: the request token and secret token are received from Tumblr; the app builds the authorization link; and when redirecting the user, it fails (again: only in Internet Explorer, latest version as well as lower versions).

The returning url from Tumblr is:
[www.myurl.com]?oauth_token=[token]&oauth_verifier=[verifiertoken]#*=*

The url thats build then for the user to go to is:
http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={$token}

Has this ever happened to anyone else? If yes, your help would be appreciated big time!

Comment: I don't quite understand from your post where the different behaviour is creeping in. All the interactions with the Tumbler API are on your server, where presumably the browser makes no difference. Perhaps with this bit (_the app builds the authorization link; and when redirecting the user, it fails_) readers could do with a bit more detail. The app is on the server, so presumably the API call on the server has been successful? When you say it fails, can you add more detail to that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the cause. This problem occurred due to the following triviality: my local Internet Explorer browser doesn't work right. It doesn't remove cookies nor temporary internet files after using the 'remove browser history' option with all switches on. I browsed to my app with other computers MSIE browsers and it DID work. I removed all history files of my MSIE manually and now it also works on my local computer. This took some hours of frustration, so I post my answer in cause someone else experiences the same issue.